# StackNavigator contains no configuration file error react native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, visual-studio-code, ios-simulator

After changing my babel.config.js file to .json, I'm running into an issue with my StackNavigator.js file wherein I get this error:

[image: Error Message]

Here is my StackNavigator.js file:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import SearchPage from './SearchPage';
import HomePage from './HomePage';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import _default from "@react-navigation/native/lib/typescript/src/ServerContainer";

const StackNavigator = () => {


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator(
    {
        search: SearchPage,
        home: HomePage,
    }
);

return (
    <NavigationContainer> 
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name = 'home' component = {HomePage}/>
            <Stack.Screen name = "search" component = {SearchPage}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
);

};

export default StackNavigator;
```

Note: I do not get this error when using babel.config.js, instead I run into this:

[image: Error 2]

Is there a second config file that references the babel config file that i need to change?